# Is using reader from CreateDataReader different from looping on Datatable.Rows

Tags: c#, datatable

I read an excel file and put it in a `Datatable`.
If I put a breakpoint and inspect the value of `myDatatable.Rows.Count()` it is equal to the number of rows in my excel file. 
But then I pass my datatable object to a method like this:

```
private void Foo(Datatable dt)
{
   DataTableReader reader = dt.CreateDataReader();
   while(reader.Read())
   {
        // do stuff on each row 
   }
}
```

Now if I put a counter inside my `while loop`, it shows for example 10 while the number of rows are really 100000.
What is it I am doing wrong?

Comment: "Now if I put a counter inside my while loop", --- That counter will show a different *(incremented)* value for each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work similar to a `for-each` loop on `DataTable.Rows`
I am guessing somewhere in your `while loop` you are exiting out of the loop. Make sure you have used "`break`" and "`continue`" correctly.

Comment: Magic! Replaced "break" with "continue"

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think anything's wrong? The table will have e.g. 100000 rows, that won't change. The DataReader, iterating over the table one row at a time, will have a different position on each iteration.

Comment: please explain more! doesn't it go row by row?

Comment: The DataTableReader allows forward only, read only access to the DataTable, starts at the first row and moves to the next when Read() or NextResult() is called. The position of the DataTableReader does not affect the overall length of the table. Think of it like climbing a ladder; the ladder (DataTable) will always have 12 rungs, but as you climb, you (DataTableReader) move from the 1st to the 12th accordingly.